# Ajax running only once in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a list of saved items that the user can delete if he wants.
They are inside a `#div`, a `delete` button next to each item.
If I press the `delete` button after the favorite items list page is loaded, it works fine.

But, if I want to delete another item, as I press on the `delete` button, the delete function would not run.

There is my AJAX:

```
$(".substitut").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();      
    var product = $(this).val();               
    var url = '/register/delete/';   
    $.ajax({        
        url: url,        
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            'product': product,            
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data['success'])            
            $("#fav_list").load(" #fav_list > *");       
        }
    }); 
});
```

and my HTML:

```
<button type ='button' class=' btn substitut' value='{{ saved.id }}'>{% csrf_token %}<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button>
```

One quick trick I found was to add `location.reload(true);` after the div refresh but the point of all of this is not having my page refreshing.

Comment: `<button type="button"...` and no form needed

Comment: Alternative: `$(".form_id").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); const product = $(this).find(".substitut").val(); ...` INSTEAD of click

Comment: Poor naming to have a class=form_id

Comment: I've tried the alternative with no luck. Should I get rid of the form and use the click event on the button?

Comment: Yes. And make it a button

Comment: I've changed my code as suggested, but now the Ajax runs only once. Question has been updated with my new code.

Comment: If the button is part of the page you load you need to do `$("#fav_list").on("click", ".substitut", function ...`